# Connect Node.js API to virtual machine on Microsoft Azure / Azure CLI

Tags: node.js, azure

Currently, I'm working on a project which is hosted on Microsoft Azure as a resource. The project is presented on a virtual machine and is operated using commands on the Azure CLI.
Now I've been asked to create a web app for it using Node.js and React.js. I'm totally lost on how to connect the Node.js API to the virtual machine. Is there any way to trigger those Azure CLI commands through a Node.js app. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
Managed to solve the issue. Used this npm package 'ssh-exec' which lets you execute commands on a virtual machine remotely after connecting using IP Address, username, password. Very simple to use.

Link to package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh-exec

Comment: Is the below answer provided by AjaykumarGhose-MT was helpful? If so could please accept the answer as solution.

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT Managed to solve the issue by myself. Have added my solution in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue. Used this npm package 'ssh-exec' which lets you execute commands on a virtual machine remotely after connecting using IP Address, username, password. Very simple to use.

Link to package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh-exec

Answer (score 0):

There are some few steps to connect Node.js API to VM,
Firstly, we need to clone the project that we will be deploying to the Azure VM. This project is a basic Node.js API with a single endpoint for returning an array of  `todo`  objects. Go to the location where you want to store the project and clone it:

```
git clone --single-branch --branch base-project https://github.com/coderonfleek/node-azure-vm.git
```

Once the project has been cloned, go to the root of the project and install dependencies:

```
cd node-azure-vm
npm install
```

Run the application using the  `npm run dev`  command. The application will start up at the address  `http://localhost:5000`. When the application is up and running, enter  `http://localhost:5000/todos`  in your browser to see the list of  `todos`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hM5D.png)

Now, go to the  `package.json`  file of your project and add these scripts in the  `scripts`  sections:

```
"scripts": {
    .....,
    "stop": "pm2 kill",
    "start": "pm2 start server.js"
}
```

The  `start`  and  `stop`  scripts will use the  [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)  process manager to start and stop the Node.js application on the VM. The  `pm2`  script will be installed globally on the VM when it has been set up.

At the root of the project, run the  `rm -rf .git`  command to remove any  `.git`  history. Then  [push the project to GitHub](https://circleci.com/blog/pushing-a-project-to-github/). Make sure that this is the GitHub account connected to your CircleCI account.

Then, Setting up a virtual machine on Azure to run Node.js.
Next, create a new VM on Azure and set its environment up for hosting the Node.js application. These are the steps:

1. Create a new VM instance
2. Install  [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/)
3. Configure  `nginx`  to act as a proxy server. Route all traffic to port  `80`  on your VM to the running instance of the Node.js application on port  `5000`
4. Install Node.js on the VM and clone the app from the GitHub repo into a folder in the VM
5. Install  `pm2`  globally

Do not be intimidated by the complexity of these steps! You can complete all five with one command. At the root of your project, create a new file named  `cloud-init-github.txt`; it is a  [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)  file. Cloud-init is an industry-standard method for cloud instance initialization.
cloud init- code

(REFER THE BELOW LINK FOR COMPLETE DETAILS)

https://circleci.com/blog/cd-azure-vm/